# How to send array (a text with commas) as HTTP-param using Rest Assured (Java)

Tags: rest-assured

I use Rest Assured framework (Java).

I need to send integer array as http-param in get request: http://example.com:8080/myservice?data_ids=11,22,33

```
    Integer[] ids = new Integer[] {11, 22, 33};

    ...

    RequestSpecificationImpl request = (RequestSpecificationImpl)RestAssured.given();
    request.baseUri("http://example.com");
    request.port(8080);
    request.basePath("/myservice");

    ...

    String ids_as_string = Arrays.toString(ids).replaceAll("\\s|[\\[]|[]]", "");
    request.params("data_ids", ids_as_string);

    System.out.println("Params: " + request.getRequestParams().toString());
    System.out.println("URI" + request.getURI());
```

What I see in the console:

```
Params: {data_ids=11,22,33}
URI: http://example.com:8080/myservice?data_ids=11%2C22%2C33
```

Why do my commas transform into '%2C'?

What needs to be done to ensure that commas are passed as they should?

Answer (score 1):

Disable URL encoding, simple as that

```
given().urlEncodingEnabled(false);
```

[Official documentation](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#url-encoding)

Verified locally,

[image]